# Wordpress Pagination - Not working (can't access second page)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I wrote here yesterday but I didn't receive any answers regarding my problem so I will try again. I have problem with my wordpress pagiation, everything is working fine but I can't access any other page than my first one because it displays an error that the page is not found. Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
get_header();?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


<?php 

  $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;


  $query_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'all_products',
      'posts_per_page' => 2,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'page' => $paged
    );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); ?>




  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <article class="loop">
        <div class="product">
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Description:</strong> <?php echo(types_render_field( "description_of_the_product", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></li>
                <li><strong>Type:</strong> <?php echo(types_render_field( "type", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></li>
                <li><strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo(types_render_field( "price", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></li>
                <li><strong>Manufacturer:</strong> <?php echo(types_render_field( "manufacturer", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></li>
                <li><strong>Availability:</strong> <?php echo(types_render_field( "availability:", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></li>
                <li><strong>Reference:</strong> <?php echo(types_render_field( "reference", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            <ul>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>         
        </div>
      </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->
    <?php
     if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) {
        custom_pagination($the_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
      }
    ?>

<?php next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages ); ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  <?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is the functions.php :

```
<?php function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }

  /**
   * This first part of our function is a fallback
   * for custom pagination inside a regular loop that
   * uses the global $paged and global $wp_query variables.
   * 
   * It's good because we can now override default pagination
   * in our theme, and use this function in default queries
   * and custom queries.
   */
  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
  }

  /** 
   * We construct the pagination arguments to enter into our paginate_links
   * function. 
   */
  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'index.php/page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
      echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
      echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
  }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got no anwser so I tried to create a new post so someone could see it and help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `page` and `paged` in your query. For pagination, you only need `paged`. According to the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) docs on pagination, `page` is used for static pages, not general pagination. Try:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'all_products',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you verified there are enough posts for page 2? Have you tried going to page 2 directly without using the pagination links? Is it a custom post type? Have you confirmed that you are getting what you expect for `get_query_var('paged')`?

Comment: I am using a custom post types with the slug name of "all_products" and I have 11 of them in my database. When I'm on my index page the pagination displays pages from 1 to 6 which is correct because I have declared to use only 2 posts per page. Thanks for the answer again but I don't really understand what you mean by the last question, if you could word it differently then that would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Your issue is that when you visit page 2, it is not showing you the correct posts right? Have you updated your permalinks?

Comment: @Chris Noticed that in the question it says `get_query_var('page')`. not `paged`.

Comment: yea sorry that was a typo. What I am saying is, have you verified that `get_query_var('page')` is actually what you want? If you are on page 2, is that variable actually 2?

Comment: Yes, my issue is when I visit page 2 it doesn't display my posts because I only use my custom posts, I don't use the wordpress ones. For the permalinks I'm using the custom structure which looks like this: `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` and my link looks like this(for the second page) : `http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/page/2`